# 2003 Yukon Climate Control Panel has no power

Tags: ac, climate-control, yukon

None of the buttons on climate control (power, fan, defrost, etc.) do anything.  The red and blue on the dials is lit up but the display that shows the temp and fan speed is blank.  Could this have anything to do with disconnecting the battery over the weekend?  I checked the fuses in the cabin and under the hood.

Thank you

Comment: You checked the underhand fuse? That's where the fuse is at for this ... I don't remember the fuse number off the too of my head, though. I would bet the fuse is your issue, but if it's fried, there could be bigger issues. Battery disconnect *could possibly* have caused this.

Comment: Underhood, not underhand. Autocorrect sucks.